# Variable initialization in Javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined, variable-initialization

There is something that I couldn't understand. I have the following code, which its purpose is to get the total of the two arrays.

```js
let r1;
let r2;
let total;

function totalSum(arr_1, arr_2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr_1.length; i++) r1 += arr_1[i];
  for (let j = 0; j < arr_2.length; j++) r2 += arr_2[j];
  total = r1 + r2;
  return total;
}

let arr_1 = [3, 5, 22, 5, 7, 2, 45, 75, 89, 21, 2]; // --> 276
let arr_2 = [9, 2, 42, 55, 71, 22, 4, 5, 90, 25, 26]; // --> 351

totalSum(arr_1, arr_2);

console.log(`total=${total} r1=${r1} r2=${r2}`);
```

- When I tried to print the result it printed "NaN" for all variables (`r1`, `r2`, and `total`).
- However, after I initialized the `r1` and `r2`. It returned the  desired outcome.

```
let r1 = 0;
let r2 = 0;
let total;
```

My question is, why do the `r1` and `r2` couldn't get the sum of the arrays without the initialization? While the variable `total` could get the result of `r1` and `r2` even though it wasn't initialized?

Comment: try `console.log(undefined+1)` . initalize without value gives undefined. total works without initilizng because you are not adding but reassigning a value

Comment: Just an FYI you could remove one of the loops (assuming you know they're both the same size) and just do `for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) { total += arr1[i] + arr2[i]; }`

Comment: Because with `r1 += ...` you are doing `undefined + 1` in the very first iteration and that's `NaN`. When you assign `total = r1 + r2` you are assiging the result of `r1 +r2` to total and replacing any prior value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is because you are adding `r1 += arr_1[i];` which means `undefined+=arr_1[i]` for the first time. since undefined cannot be added with, it returns `NaN` for each and every addition done from first to last. But in `total` case, you are assigning the value `total=r1+r2` so in that case even if total was `undefined` it was reassigned another value, which was `r1 + r2`. So in short, you cannot add to an `undefined` value but you can assign another variable to an `undefined` value. Hope it answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

when you define a variable without assigning the value, its value by default is "undefined". in this case, you're trying to do maths with number and undefined, which will convert to NaN

Comment: While that is correct, it's not an answer to OP's question